# Is there anyway possible to refresh a getter on an ICollectionView property?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on an autocomplete textbox that has a listbox that will be populated with streetnames from a database based on what the user has entered. When my app is started the getter on my property returns null because the user has not typed anything into the textbox just yet. What I am trying to accomplish is to somehow refresh the getter after the streets have been returned from the api call. I also have an `OnPropertyChanged` in my setter that does not seem to be working. Any suggestions? Thank you.

```
public ICollectionView Streets
{
    get { return streets; }

    set
    {
            streets = value;                   
            OnPropertyChanged("Streets");
            Streets.Refresh();                
    }                    
}
```

The streets being added to the list here (which works very nicely):

```
public void AddToList()
{
    var streetNames = new ObservableCollection<Street>();                              
    {
        streetNames.Add(new Street() { StreetName = "Mockingbird Ln" });
        streetNames.Add(new Street() { StreetName = "Shoeman Ln" });
        streetNames.Add(new Street() { StreetName = "Gingerbread Drive" });
        foreach (var street in StreetNames)
        {
            streetNames.Add(new Street() {StreetName = street});
        }

    };
    streets = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(streetNames);
    streets.Filter = ContainsFilter;

}
```

Listbox Xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="StreetListBox"  Visibility="Collapsed" Background="White" Margin="138,548,35,381"   
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Streets, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedStreet}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:String}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StreetName}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I do this by binding to IEnemerable and NotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your ViewModel. If you don't, `PropertyChanged` event won't be listened by your View, hence it won't call your getter.

Other problem I see in your code is in XAML `DataType="{x:Type System:String}"` which is wrong. Your data is of type `Street`, hence your XAML should look something like:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Street}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StreetName}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: My ViewModel does have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented through a bindable base class, is there something that I need to add to it?

Comment: No, if it is implemented in the base class, you don't need to "reimplement" it.